# Minimum speed for a cube to overturn at a stop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am trying to solve this problem, is about an homogeneous cube of side ${L}$ traveling with a constant velocity on a horizontal frictionless surface and I'm asked to find whats the minimum speed for it to overturn at a stop ${S}$ on the surface, the stop is massless.

[image]

Because it is traveling at a constant speed, linear momentum and angular momentum are conserved and I tried using that but I'm not sure which tool to use to prove that the cube effectively overturned, because it may gain angular velocity because of the sudden stop but may not overturn.

Comment: Looks like a problem on the topic of conservation of energy

Comment: I think the deceleration rate has a lot to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liner momentum and angular momentum are *not* conserved because there is a force acting on the cube at S.

Instead of using momentum, think about energy instead. If the cube tips over then energy is needed to raise the centre of mass of the cube from its initial height $\frac L 2$ to a height of $\frac L {\sqrt 2}$ when the COM is vertically above S. Where does this energy come from ?

Comment: Thats gravitational energy, thanks!, that helped me solve it